# React JS Cambiar DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Desarrollo una App en `REACT JS` que con un `botón` debería cambiar la presentación de los items.

Es decir si pulso `grilla` debería mostrarme en `cuadrícula`, al pulsar `lista`, pues todo enlazado con las especificación del item.

mi componente `<Products />` ya lo tengo invocado que se imprime sin problemas, ¿cómo cambiaria por `<Products2 />` en mismo `panel` ya de manera diferente?

¿alguna idea o sugerencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que en **JQuery** podemos lograrlo con:

```
$("#bgrilla").click(function(){
  // Limpiamos Contenedor
  $("#contenedor").html("");
  // Volvemos a listar datos
  $.get("",function(r){
    // r , seria el resultado que nos trae la Lista de datos
    // codigo para imprimir en grilla
  });
});

$("#blista").click(function(){
  // Limpiamos Contenedor
  $("#contenedor").html("");
  // Volvemos a listar datos
  $.get("",function(r){
    // r , seria el resultado que nos trae la Lista de datos
    // codigo para imprimir en Lista
  });
});
```

y este es mi componete que me lista los datos en grilla

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
export default class Products extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }
  addproducto(i) {
    this.props.addproducto(i);
  }
  imagen(item) {
    if (item.imagen != '') {
      return (
        <img
          alt={item.description}
          className="ima"
          src={'assets/pro/' + item.imagen}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return <img alt={item.description} className="ima" src="https://" />;
    }
  }
  render() {
    const items = this.props.lista.map((item, i) => (
      <div key={i} className="col-sm-3">
        <div onClick={this.addproducto.bind(this, i)} className="producto">
          <div className="imagen" id={'producto' + item.id}>
            {this.imagen(item)}
            <div id={'marca' + item.id} className="marca0"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="justify-content-center text-center">
            <h6>
              {item.nombre} {item.description}
            </h6>
            <h5>{item.coins.symbol + item.PVP}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
    return (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        component={React.Fragment}
        transitionName="example"
        transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
      >
        {items}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añade eventos a los iconos de grilla y demás de manera que puedas gestionar los estados.

En el componente padre, puedes utilizar algún tipo de variable en el state que cambie la configuración, por ejemplo

crea un estado:

```
state = {
  viewType: "grilla"
}
```

crea un manejador del evento;

```
handleViewTypeChange(type) {
  this.setState({ viewType: type});
}
```

Y luego tendrías algo así en el render

```
if (this.state.viewType === 'grilla') {
  return <Products onViewTypeChange={this.handleViewTypeChange} />
} 
return <Products2 onViewTypeChange={this.handleViewTypeChange} />
```

P.D. Es una buena práctica setear los bindeos en el constructor

```
constructor() {
super();

this.addproducto = this.addproducto.bind(this);
}
```

[documentación oficial](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md)
y
[documentación oficial](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react)